# Repeated Items in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I am having problems with repeated items in RecyclerView. Whenever I upload to my firebase and open the main activity again there are repeated itmes in the recyclerView from the previous load. How do I remove repeated items from my recyclerView.

Code for my Main Activity is

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private List<Upload> mUploads;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts);
    setupBottomNavigation();

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



    mUploads = new ArrayList<>();


    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

    mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                mUploads.add(upload);
            }
            mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, mUploads);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    Button btn_post = (Button) findViewById(R.id.post_Main);
    btn_post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent_posts = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Posts.class);
            startActivity(intent_posts);

        }
    });

}
```

Code from my Adapter class is

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.rViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Upload> mUploads;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads){
    mContext = context;
    mUploads = uploads;
}

@Override
public rViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.card_view_recycler_view, parent, false);
    return new rViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull rViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
    viewHolder.textViewDescription.setText(uploadCurrent.getDescription());
    Picasso.get().load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl()).into(viewHolder.imageView);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUploads.size();
}


public class rViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView textViewDescription;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public  rViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.r_description);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.r_image_view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this happens because firebase store data offline, try below way to initialise instance

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(false);
```

should work.

Comment: have you try clean array list before fill it?

Comment: I tried doing that, it didnt work. According to the documentation, the recyclerView stores the contents in memory, and I have no idea how to clear it from that

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your List before addind data to it as shown below.

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private List<Upload> mUploads;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts);
    setupBottomNavigation();

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



    mUploads = new ArrayList<>();


    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

    mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                mUploads.clear();
                mUploads.add(upload);
            }
            mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, mUploads);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    Button btn_post = (Button) findViewById(R.id.post_Main);
    btn_post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent_posts = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Posts.class);
            startActivity(intent_posts);

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your ArrayList in this case `mUploads` before adding items to it i.e.,

```
mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Clear ArrayList
        mUploads.clear();
        for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
            mUploads.add(upload);
        }
        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, mUploads);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

This works well on my end and I hope it helps.
[Reference here.](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-to-stop-the-items-duplication-in-recyclerview-android)

Answer (score 0):

If you uninstall the app and install it again and there are duplicate items in the list the first time you run the app after installing, then there are duplicate items in the backend Firebase. If there are duplicate items only the second time you run the app then your code is responsible.

The code you have showed looks good to me. There have to be something else your not showing like by mistake you have duplicate `addValueEventListener` or you are feeding the Adapter a second time with the `List<Upload> mUploads`

As many suggest here that you do the `mUploads.clear();` is not necessary since you populating the array from the `onCreate()`, witch only run once during Activity lifecykle

I would move the `private List<Upload> mUploads;` inside the `onCreate()` as a local variable if your not using it elsewhere